# MYSQL virtual column average

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a database for film reviews to use for a homepage for some friends of mine.

I want to make a virtual column that adds all movie characters (from 1-6) and makes an average.

My database is like this:

```
Nummer|Navn|Forfatter|Sted|Dato|Karakter|Martin|Lars|Lund|Bjorn|Mikkel|Henrik|Silve|Olsen|Jørgen|Amund|Einar

One entry is for instance like this:

3|Garden State|Lars|Felix Kino|2005-01-03|5.11 |5|5|5|0|5|0|5|5|5|0|5|
```

But I want the column [Karakter] (average rating of movie) to be a virtual column.

My problem is that, as you see, not everyone of my friends watch every movie.

So how can I automatically make a column with the average rating?

edit:

Entered a lot of info and made two tables. One with individual ratings and one with basic movie info

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxlVX.png ||
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XY9q.png

Where you thinking I should do more like this place I found: (Link is in bottom of Joachim Isaksson's post since stackoverflow hinder me in making a link)

I feel the table arrangement in the link is not so good really. Isn't that very case sensitive? what if i spell a name slightly wrong wrong. That would mess up the result.

edit2: Very messy but stackoverflow hindered me in making links and stuff sorry

edit3: After a long time I have put everything in tables like I was told to do. Final code should be like this:

```
SELECT m.*, AVG(r.rating) AS average
FROM movie m
JOIN rating r
  ON m.id = r.movie_id
  GROUP BY m.id
```

I have 3 tables: 1 quite short list with reviewers and id. One with movie info. And one with movie id, reviewer id, reviewer grade.

Comment: what do you mean with virtual column? you can calculate the average on select when you fetch data from the database or calculate it later in php.

Comment: You should really normalize your table to - for example - have a movie table with base movie data and a ratings table with a movie id, a user name and a rating. Having a column per friend isn't very fun when you meet a new friend, it would mean rewriting all queries against the table.

Comment: @ Lelio Faieta yeah I know. But i was hoping that it could be done easier. I use XAMMP and in phpmyadmin I have a choice to make virtual and then add a function to the column. For instance I tried and set the function to Martin+Lars+Lund and so on. And that worked! But i don't know how to get average value. @Joachim Isaksson Sounds smart. But for now I just want something up running.

Comment: What if I want to list the database acending based on movie grade. Isn't it much better to have the grade in the database? Other than running a (big?) script computing all the averages of all the movies. I have done quite some reading at w3schools.com (I like that site alot). But I kinda want something concrete. I started this project 10 years ago lol. It gets demotivating to read and read with very little real world application.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Maybe if i get this virtual column going couldn't I say something like add all columns right off 7. And when I add a friend and the Grade column get updated automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work for you with the current table structure;

```
SELECT *,
    (`Martin` + `Lars` + `Lund` + `Bjorn` + `Mikkel` + `Henrik` + 
     `Silve` + `Olsen` + `Jorgen` + `Amund` + `Einar`)
   /
    ((`Martin`!=0) + (`Lars`!=0) + (`Lund`!=0) + (`Bjorn`!=0) + (`Mikkel`!=0) + 
     (`Henrik`!=0) + (`Silve`!=0) + (`Olsen`!=0) + (`Jorgen`!=0) + (`Amund`!=0) + 
     (`Einar`!=0)) AS average 
FROM myTable
```

...with all names hard coded in the SQL.

If you would split movie to one table and reviews to another table, you'd instead get something close to this;

```
SELECT m.*, AVG(r.rating) AS average
FROM movie m
JOIN rating r
  ON m.id = r.movie_id
```

...with no hard dependencies on names or number of friends.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this.

Comment: Sorry to bother you more, but now I have made 2 tables as you said one with movie info and one with invidual ratings of every person. Everything you said seems good. Just that I want to add all columns in each row so I can get average of each movie. Your AVG function add rows not columns. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: where you thinking like this: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/10/05/how-to-count-values-with-mysql-queries/

Comment: SELECT m.*, AVG(r.rating) AS average
FROM movie m
JOIN rating r
  ON m.id = r.movie_id
group by m.id ................should be the right call. I have put everything in tables. Took a while. You missed the group by m.id line at the bottom